# can't pass value in select option

Tags: php

This is my code in test1.php

```
<?php
if ($_POST['check']!= ""){
$a = $_POST['translation'];

}
?>
<html>
<form action="test2.php" method="post">
<select name="translation">
<option selected="selected" value="1">Vietnamese-English</option>
<option value="2">English-Vietnamese</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Check" name="check">
</form>
</html>
```

and in test2.php I just echo the value `$a` but I get nothing. The value is NULL when I use `var_dump($a)`

Comment: How do you think `$a` gets set if you send the form to test2.php ?

Comment: $a will have the value that chosen from the user in the 2 options

Comment: Nope, it will never reaches this code, because you send it straight to test2.php if you submit your form

Comment: i dont get it, i thought when the check button clicked, it will store the $_POST['translation'] into $a and then pass to test2.php. Sorry that i am new to PHP

Comment: Maybe this helps you: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this. Doing `if ($_POST['check']!= ""){
$a = $_POST['translation']; echo $a;
}` and `action=""` worked perfectly. I don't know what results you're looking to get. Show us what you have for code in test2.php

Comment: This `<?php
if ($_POST['check']!= ""){
$a = $_POST['translation'];

}
?>` belongs in test2.php and not part of test1.php remove it.

Comment: ok i get it. Thx for your reference

Comment: If you wish to have me post an answer and you can accept it to close the question, it's up to you. If not, you can just delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of your code in your form, doesn't belong there:

```
<?php
if ($_POST['check']!= ""){
$a = $_POST['translation'];

// echo $a; // I added this
}
?>
```

It belongs in your test2.php file, that is why you are not getting results.